Cant Insert Data from Nested Json in Clickhouse
I have some json file, i save in s3, the structure is like this
{
  "testing_field": "tambahan",
  "test_update_2": {
    "code_1": "5B72F80DA8",
    "path_2": "xxx",
    "filename_2": "xxx.pdf",
    "qrcode_2": "xxx"
  }
}

I tried the select function first to test the data retrieval, like this,
SELECT
test_update_2.filename_2
FROM s3(
    'xxxx/sample_update_field.json',
    'xxx',
    'xxx'
)

i can get the result, like this,
xxx.pdf
xxx.pdf

after that, i create a new field in table, because i search and get this notes
You cannot change the column name by adding a dot (.) in the column name directly because ClickHouse uses the dot (.) as a separator between the database and table name. Therefore, using a dot in the column name will cause a conflict with the existing syntax.
I made the column names as follows
Executing query: ALTER TABLE sidebar_staging ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS testing_field Nullable(String);
Executing query: ALTER TABLE sidebar_staging ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS test_update_2_code_1 Nullable(String);
Executing query: ALTER TABLE sidebar_staging ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS test_update_2_filename_2 Nullable(String);
Executing query: ALTER TABLE sidebar_staging ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS test_update_2_path_2 Nullable(String);
Executing query: ALTER TABLE sidebar_staging ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS test_update_2_qrcode_2 Nullable(String);

I replace the (.) to (_)
But when i try to insert with this query
INSERT INTO example_db.sidebar_staging (test_update_2_filename_2)
SELECT
test_update_2.filename_2
FROM s3(
    'xxx/sample_update_field.json',
    'xxx'
    'xxx'
)

data not entered into the destination field,
then i thing i must add alias, and i try this query,
INSERT INTO example_db.sidebar_staging (test_update_2_filename_2)
    SELECT
    test_update_2.filename_2 as test_update_2_filename_2
    FROM s3(
        'xxx/sample_update_field.json',
        'xxx'
        'xxx'
    )

but the result is same, i think i must be test the testing_field  because is not in nested json, with this code
INSERT INTO example_db.sidebar_staging (testing_field)
SELECT
testing_field
FROM s3(
    'xxx/sample_update_field.json',
    'xxx',
    'xxx'
)

What is surprising is that when the field name from the JSON is the same as the field name in the table, it does not require an alias and can be inserted into the target table.
Because testing_field is same in column table testing_field 
So the question is, how do you do an insert if the original field is in a nested JSON?
I have to extract with dot format (test update_2.filename 2) to get the value,
in other side i cant use dot in name column and cant used alias to mapping to column too

Have you tried using JSONExtract method (link to doc)? You should be able to achieve what you want by something like this:
INSERT INTO example_db.sidebar_staging (test_update_2_filename_2)
SELECT
    JSONExtract(test_update_2, 'filename_2', 'String') AS test_update_2_filename_2
FROM s3(
    'xxx/sample_update_field.json',
    'xxx',
    'xxx'
)

